# Python multiprocessing and file seeks

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the `multiprocessing` package to concurrently read a file and overwrite (parts of) it after some data trasformation. I understand it seems a bit abstract, but I have an use for this kink of concurrency for speedup my own [`blocksync` fork](https://github.com/shodanshok/blocksync).

Below you can find my code snipplet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import multiprocessing
import sys
import time
blocksize=1024

def do_open(f, mode):
    f = open(f, mode)
    f.seek(0, 2)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    return f, size

def pipe_getblocks(f, pipe, side):
    print "Child file object ID: "+str(id(f))
    while True:
        print "getblocks_seek_prev: "+str(f.tell())
        block = f.read(blocksize)
        if not block:
            break
        print "getblocks_seek_next: "+str(f.tell())
        pipe.send(block)

def pipe_server(dev):
    f, size = do_open(dev, 'r+')
    parent,child = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
    reader = multiprocessing.Process(target=pipe_getblocks, args=(f,child,"R"))
    reader.daemon = True
    reader.start()
    child.close()
    i = 0
    print "Parent file object ID:"+str(id(f))
    while True:
        try:
            block = parent.recv()
        except:
            break
        else:
            print str(i)+":pseek: "+str(f.tell()/1024/1024)
            f.seek(0,0) # This seek should not be see in the child subprocess...
            i = i+1

pipe_server("/root/random.img")
```

Basically, the parent process should wait for the child to populate the pipe, then read from it. Please pay attention to the `f.seek(0,0)` line: I put it here to verify that parent and child each have its own idea of where to seek in the file. In other words, being two different processes entirely, I expect that a `f.seek` done on parent had no effect on its child.

However, it seems that this assumption is wrong, as the above program produce the following output:

```
Child file object ID: 140374094691616
getblocks_seek_prev: 0
getblocks_seek_next: 1024
...
getblocks_seek_next: 15360
getblocks_seek_prev: 15360
getblocks_seek_next: 16384
getblocks_seek_prev: 16384
getblocks_seek_next: 17408 <-- past EOF!
getblocks_seek_prev: 17408 <-- past EOF!
getblocks_seek_next: 18432 <-- past EOF!
getblocks_seek_prev: 18432 <-- past EOF!
...
Parent file object ID:140374094691616
0:pseek: 0
1:pseek: 0
2:pseek: 0
3:pseek: 0
4:pseek: 0
5:pseek: 0
6:pseek: 0
7:pseek: 0
8:pseek: 0
9:pseek: 0
10:pseek: 0
...
```

As you can see, the child process **read past its EOF** or, well, it *think* so, because it is really reading from the start of the file. In short, it appear that the parent's `f.seek(0,0)` has effect on the child process, without it recognizing that.

My assumption is that the file object is stored on shared memory, so both processes are modifing the same data/object. This idea seems confirmed by the `id(f)` taken from both parent and child processes, which report identical data. However, I found no reference stating that file object are kept in shared memory when using the `multiprocessing` package.

***So, my question is: it that the expected behavior, or I am missing something obvious?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is starting the child process using `fork()`, which causes the child to inherit the file descriptors from its parent. Since they're sharing a file descriptor, they also share the same seek offsets. From the manpage of `fork(2)`:

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
>             descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same
>             open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file
>             descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two file
>             descriptors share open file status flags, file offset, and signal-
>             driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and
>             F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

Python `file` objects on unix are very thin wrappers over file descriptors (the implementation in Python currently boils down to an fdno and some metadata about the path; [the `seek()` method is just calling `lseek(2)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/99d1075f8a0f4367fce07cc4bf61c35ea7cd97ac/Modules/_io/fileio.c#L950)), so cloning the object into the child process is basically just sending a file descriptor across.

The easiest solution I can think of is to pass the path to the child process and open the file in each process separately. You could maybe do some tricky stuff with `os.dup`, but I'm not sure that there would be any advantages to that beyond saving some bytes when you spawn the new process.

Comment: Very clear explanation, and +1 for citing man page. I know quite well C-based forks so, if Python only provides a thin wrapper around them, this basically **is** expected behavior.

Comment: Double thinking about that: with fork, the current offset is inherited by the child, but its file descriptor copy should have its own private seek position, so I am not sure how parent's f.seek() done after forking 'leaks' to child process...

Comment: No, both processes have the same file descriptor. FDs are an OS-provided token that represent a file and a position; both processes end up with the same token, so both end up seeing any changes to the underlying FD. FDs are not a struct that libc/Python/whatever can mutate, they're just integers that map onto an array in the kernel.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for file descriptor is quite good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: Ok, so Python does not get in the way of masking/abstracting what a FD really is. Thank you very much, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a separate open for each child process. Instead of passing the file object as an argument, try passing the path to the file instead, then open inside the function that multiprocessing calls.

Comment: Yeah, this is a possible workaround, thank you. However, I am more interested in **why**  if it is happening and it this is expected behavior.